# How to read HTTP headers with Jenkins, when using generic webhook trigger

Tags: http, jenkins, bitbucket

in bitbucket I trigger jenkins by using a webhook. I added the jenkins url and I can read the body of the HTTP request. For this I used a Generic Webhook in Jenkins and added the variable names. I looks on Jenkins site like this.
[Jenkins Generic Webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Tgu.png)

No I want to read the header as well. but somehow I dont know how to do this. My aim is it to read the X-Hub-Signature and then compare with the Bitbucket Signature.
The header of Bitbucket is described here
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver076/event-payload-1026535078.html

I can see from Bitbucket that it is sending the X-Hub-Signature but cant figure out how to recieve it on jenkin site. If somehow has an advice, then I would be grateful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got help here https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69142 So i guess it is fine for me now